# Is it possible to Sum columns if columns name is like '2020%'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table on my server where they have already pivoted the data so now I am sitting with a table that looks something like this.

| Client_No | 20200201 | 20200401 | 20220101 | 20220201 | 20220301 | 20220401 | 20220501 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 321654987 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

this table gets updated monthly so to automate the script I want to be able to do something like this

```
Select Client_No
, Sum(column like '2022%')
From [table_name]
```

Is this possible? Basically I want the script to sum all the columns that start with 2022, and yes I am currently running this in SSMS

Comment: I have *assumed* you are using SQL Server here. If you are using a different product that you can connect to using SSMS, such as Azure SQL Database, or Azure Synapse, please [edit] your question to correct the tag(s).

Comment: `SUM` is performed on a column, what would you expect `SUM(column like '2022%'))` to do? `SUM` the first column it finds with a name like that? Though, the problem here appears to be your design, especially so if you are adding a new column to it each month.

Comment: I am using Mircosoft SQL server Studio

Comment: *"Mircosoft SQL server Studio"* I assume by this you mean SQL Server Management Studio. SSMS isn't an (R)DBMS, it's an IDE-like application which is (predominately) used with SQL Server. This is why I stated I *assume* you are using SQL Server but asked you to correct the tags if not, as SSMS <> SQL Server. Saying you are using SSMS when asked what (R)DBMS you are using is like replying "Microsoft Excel" when asked what operating system you are using; it gives us a likely candidate (Windows), but not a definite one (as Excel can be run on Macs, and in a browser).

Comment: Can you first unpivot your columns [Unpivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) . Prepare us some sample data.

Comment: Telling us you use "Studio" is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the name you see on the dashboard radio: okay for most, but alarming if the person talking claims to be a mechanic.

Comment: Can you use the data from before the pivot instead?

Comment: no, the original data is handled by another department and they refuse to change, or even give us a replicated database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you already have **table** which is pivoted you will have to unpivot it first.

```
SELECT CLIENT_NO, SUM(CAST(ORDERS AS BIGINT)) OrdersNumber FROM (

    SELECT Client_No, Years, Orders  
    FROM   
       (SELECT Client_No,[20200201], [20220101], [20200401], [20220201]
       FROM myTable) p  
    UNPIVOT  
       (Orders FOR Years IN   
          ([20200201], [20200401], [20220101], [20220201])  
    )AS unpvt

) SRC
WHERE LEFT(SRC.Years,4) = '2022'
GROUP BY CLIENT_NO
```

Or if you don't want to put down all columns you can use dynamic unpivot

```
DECLARE @Pivot_Column [nvarchar](max);  
DECLARE @Query [nvarchar](max);  
   
set @Pivot_Column = (SELECT STRING_AGG('[' + cName + ']', ',') FROM  
(select c.Name cName from sys.all_columns c
left join sys.objects o on c.object_id = o.object_id 
where o.name = 'MyTable' and c.name <> 'Client_No' )Tab  
)


SELECT @Query='
SELECT CLIENT_NO, SUM(CAST(ORDERS AS BIGINT)) OrdersNumber FROM (

    SELECT Client_No, Years, Orders  
    FROM   
       (SELECT Client_No,' + @Pivot_Column +  '
       FROM myTable) p  
    UNPIVOT  
       (Orders FOR Years IN   
          (' + @Pivot_Column +  ')  
    )AS unpvt

) SRC
WHERE LEFT(SRC.Years,4) = ''2022''
GROUP BY CLIENT_NO
'   
EXEC  sp_executesql  @Query
```

Note: You can use STRING_AGG starting from [SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: unfortunately we are still using Version 12, however the First query seems to do EXACTLY what I needed... Thanks a million!

Comment: @Flaniganga the main disadvantage of first query is that each time you get new columns you will have to change query. Better approach is to use second query. Even if you have Version 12 you can change STRING_AGG to and it should work ```Select @Pivot_Column = COALESCE(@Pivot_Column+',','')+ QUOTENAME([cName]) FROM  
(select c.Name cName from sys.all_columns c
left join sys.objects o on c.object_id = o.object_id 
where o.name = 'MyTable' and c.name <> 'Client_No' )Tab ```

Answer (score 1):

To do a `Sum`, you usually need a `GROUP BY` clause. In this case you might be better-off using a sub-query to create a calculated column for grouping. Try this:

```
SELECT Client_No, Yr, Sum(ItemValue)
FROM (
    Select Client_No, 
           Left(datemask_or_whatever, 4) as Yr, --column like '2022%'
           ItemValue
    From [table_name]
) SubQuery
GROUP BY Client_No, Yr
```